# How to download and install the extension to magento connect from GitHub repository?

Tags: magento, download

I have private repository in GitHub for Magento module development but I can't create package for Magento conenct from GitHub. Is there any option to create package?

If anyone can help here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a tool to generate a package for magento connect from a git repository right now. You have to install your module an package it in magento itself. Here is the [official tutorial pdf](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf).